# Why does interaction with keyboard script crash Python entirely?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Pressing the 'm' key crashes Idle.

I tried replacing the fatal script using modules like pygame, psutil and getch.
I did some digging through the Internet, but I found nothing.

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

root=tk.Tk()
start = tk.Message(root, text = "Spróbuj mnie zaMknąć! Jeśli uMiesz...")
start.config(bg = 'black', fg = "#00ff00", font = ('times',24,'bold'))
start.pack()

def on_closing():
    root.overrideredirect(True)
    pass
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

m = 0
try:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('m'):
        print(m)
    else:
        pass
except:
   print('Nope.')
```

I expect the program to print 0, but instead, I get message from Windows that Python has stopped responding and will be closed.

Comment: The tkinter has nothing to do with printing the value of `m`. Try to present a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I ran this on Ubuntu Linux, and was informed that to use the module (probably referring to keyboard) I had to be root; i.e. admin, for Windows. See if that will change anything?

Comment: @PoiKozi I also never understood that. Pynput has almost the same functionality and doesn't require root.

Comment: Also, one has to specifically appreciate the important `else: pass`.

Comment: @PoiKozi I wouldn't say that, it might well be that tkinter causes the keyboard library to crash, they both interact with the same keyboard.

Comment: Add `raise` at the same indent after `print(‘Nope’)`? (Or delete the whole `except:`)